# Trying to redirect http://.ws to another domain, but I get Bad Request - Invalid Hostname / HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid

Tags: url, dns, host, tld

I'm trying to redirect a domain I bought: [http://.ws](http://%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD.ws) to another page with GoDaddy, but all I get when I visit the site is:

```
"Bad Request - Invalid Hostname / HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid."
```

I have redirected another domain with GoDaddy to the same page I'm now trying to, and it works normal.

Is there something wrong with the new url?

**Edit**: Looks like it was a problem with GoDaddy and I just needed to wait a few days. Maybe it works faster now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which characters make a URL invalid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid)

Comment: I get the exact same response for my domain http://xn--yh8hr9b.ws/. It seems to be a GoDaddy problem. Their domain http://xn--qeiaa.ws/ seems to work just fine.

Comment: I got the same problem with my GoDaddy emoji domain (http://✅.ws) . Any change to fix this? Have you spoken to the support already?

Comment: Haven't spoken to the support, but now it works. Just needed to wait a few days.

Comment: Having the same issue...hope it fixes itself soon... Anyone else have any luck?